# How to pass a String[] to my angular2 html template

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an array variable declared in the export class of my component;

```
 barChartLabel:string[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
```

I display this to the screen in my html template as follows

```
{{barChartLabel}}
```

but when i put that into a parameters value it fails, as follows

```
 <mychart [chartLabelObject]="[{{barChartLabel}}]"></mychart>
```

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: `[]` binds straight to variables, you need to remove the `[{{}}]` on the right hand side of the assignment. Also, this primer on template syntax is worthwhile reading: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax

Comment: thx a million @silentsod can you put that as an anwer with the a bit of code?

Comment: [chartLabelObject]="barChartLabel"

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is pass this to a child component (mychart)?

in your child component.ts :

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

export class app {

@Input() chartLabelObject:string[];

}
```

parent .component.html:

```
<app-craftinput [chartLabelObject]="barChartLabel"></app-craftinput>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html